# Python - How to make sure resource is closed

Tags: python, urllib2

I want to close f before returning from the method. I added finally blocked but it needs initialization. What to initialize it with?

```
def test_close_resource(url):
    try:
        f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        if f.code == 200:
            return True
    except Exception as error:
        return False
    finally:
        f.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the connection within a context manager using [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#examples) as:

```
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.python.org/') as f:
    print(f.read(300))
```

The connection gets closed automatically when it comes out of the context manager block defined with `with` keyword.

Comment: but in case of exception it should return false.

Comment: you can leave the exception part as it is and remove the `finally` block. if there are any exception, they'll happen with `with` block as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you're looking for is the `with` clause -

```
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://python.org/') as response:pass
```